# Bootstrap datepicker: second field to allow dates later than the selected date on first field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

When user selects a date on the first field, the second field must start on the selected date, and disallow any selection of previous date. I created a fiddle for reference 
http://jsfiddle.net/gfokvuxr/ and here is the code:

Thank you

```
<label class="form-label">Loading Date</label>


  <div class="input-append success date">
       <input type="text" name="loadingdate" id="dt1" class="span12" required >
       <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span> 
</div>


<label class="form-label">Delivery date</label>


  <div class="input-append success date">
       <input type="text" name="deliverydate" id="dt2" class="span12" required >
       <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span> 
</div>
```

this is the JS code

```
  $('.input-append.date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: new Date() 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of [the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate), it would be thus:

```
$('#loadDate').change(function(event, ui){
    $('#deliverDate').datepicker( "setDate", (Date)($( "#loadDate" ).datepicker( "getDate" )));
    $('#deliverDate').datepicker( "option", "minDate", (Date)($( "#loadDate" ).datepicker( "getDate" )));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1a09hyff/1/

Give each datepicker an ID and use those to register an event listener on the first to update the second's minDate.

That said, it isn't working for some reason; I can't get any of the modification methods (including destroy) to actually work.  A couple throw internal errors (I've been seeing a lot of those lately, where `date.getMonth()` throws `getMonth is not a function` etc).

Comment: It doesn't even load the calendar!

Comment: It would appear that the loading of the remote datepicker script is being blocked.

Comment: Dude seriously, I forked your own fiddle to create that one.  I don't know why it won't load the scripts, all I did was add the bit that I have in this answer.  Even if it doesn't work, it should at least point you in the right direction to figure out how to use the package on your own.